# Excel IFERROR returns #NAME?

Tags: excel-formula

I am using INDEX/MATCH to look up values for cells in a column against an external workbook. This is working fine, but when a value is not returned, the cell gets #N/A instead. I need to trap this error and return the value UNKNOWN. Here’s my formula:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Wards,MATCH(B28,Postcodes,0)),”UNKNOWN”)
```

Both Wards and Postcodes are named ranges in the external workbook (ranges are named locally).

However, IFERROR is returning #NAME?

No matter what I try I cannot get round this. I have tried different strategies like using IFNA, IF/ISERROR, IF/ISNA etc.

I am using Excel 2013.

I have seen a solution in Stack Overflow relating to the same problem where the function is written in VBA, and the reason given is that the error “never makes it past the MATCH function”, and hence is not trapped by IFERROR. I haven’t been able to adapt the solution to this to solve my problem.

Comment: Double check that your named ranges are truly there and spelled correctly.

Comment: Also check if your named ranges are in a worksheet scope on a different worksheet.

Comment: They are; the named ranges work perfectly where a match is found

Comment: You have stylized `”`.  Change them to `"`

Comment: Very interesting. Not something I would have spotted. Got it working. A hex comparison between the old and new strings shows I had typed 0x94 (Cancel Character)  instead of 0x22 (Quotation Mark).

Comment: Following what @Scott said I checked my quotes. I was on iPhone and was using the quotes I always used and it was giving this error. I had to long press on the quotes and choose the parallel quotes. Now it works a charm – thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I almost missed the solution that was in the comments.

Check if you have single apostrophe (') or the wrong quotes (”) around your string.

Credit goes to Scott Craner